# Combining static and dynamic routes in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am working on some legacy code that has tons of htaccess redirects that look like this:

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^login/([-A-z0-9]+)*$ ./login.php?id=$1 [R=302,NC,QSA,L]
    RewriteRule ^my-account/*$ ./my-account.php [R=302,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^legacy-path-1/*$ ./god-knows-what.php [R=302,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^legacy-path-2/*$ ./static-dynamic-page.php [R=302,NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^legacy-why-would-you-code-this-path/*$ ./king-of-spagetti-code.php [R=302,NC,L]
    .............

        # about dozen of similar lines as above
    .............
    #my last line in that mess
    RewriteRule ^another-static-link/([-A-z0-9]+)*$ ./another-one-of-many-copy-paste-pages.php?pool_id=$1 [R=302,NC,QSA,L]
```

However, we are adding new components and I implemented a custom built light-framework that uses routing.

Without re-writing entire code, I need to send URLs that did not match any rules above to **app.php** which would route per routing rules.

**So when I add this line at the end of .htaccess**

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?route_query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

*Despite the [L] flags above,* htaccess still process everything to app.php (resulting in error, naturally).

IF URL matched, how do I stop .htaccess to go further than matched line?

I thought [L] flag does that. But it doesn't.

I thought about re-writing static routes, but that's outside of the scope of our agreement.

Thank you for help.

Comment: The `[L]` flag only stops that current rule set. So if you start a new rule set, the above `[L]` flag is irrelevant. Ideally, you need to add a rewrite condition that stops already changed URLs from becoming `app.php`. You _could_ possibly use the `[S]` (SKIP) flag along with an IF,ELSE,THEN sort of layout. But I'm not sure at this moment, hence the comment! See apache flag descriptions [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteCond` scope is for very next `RewriteRule` **only**. From your example, it is only checked for the following rule `RewriteRule ^login/([-A-z0-9]+)*$ ./login.php?id=$1 [R=302,NC,QSA,L]`. In your case, when you add the wildcard rule at the end, it always matches again and again (you create a transparent infinite rewrite loop).

What you need to do is to ignore existing folders/files at the begin, then do your mess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# don't touch existing folders/files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# your mess here

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php?route_query=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You are amazing. This is what I've been missing. Thank you.